# Show elements, after task on all is done, do this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I'm having some problems to figure how I would do this task. I got a wrapper with elements, and on a click I'm gone show them. After they are visible I want to perform another task, issue here is that it triggers it for each element in the wrapper.

**EDIT**
Sorry meant to be `.fadeIn()`

example code: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HbrPs/)

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="div-item"></div>
    <div class="div-item"></div>
    <div class="div-item"></div>
    <div class="div-item"></div>
    <div class="div-item"></div>
</div>

<a href="#" id="click-me">click me</a>

$('#click-me').on('click', function()  {
    $('#wrapper > div.div-item').fadeIn(600, function() {
        console.log('show');
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: the selector you want is: `$('.div-item','#wrapper')`. I'm unsure about the function with the show method. But I could be wrong lol

Comment: if you're not animating, you can just do: `$('#wrapper > div.div-item').show();` and do whatever needs to be done, in the next line.

Comment: Why is this selector different then mine? does the same thing, still triggers the `function()` 5 times for each element inside the `#wrapper`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without animation (or other async operations) you don't need a callback, just do:

```
$('#click-me').on('click', function()  {
  $('#wrapper > div.div-item').show();
  // follow-up code

  return false;
});
```

Otherwise, try:

```
$('#click-me').on('click', function()  {
  $('#wrapper > div.div-item').fadeIn().promise().done(function () {
    console.log('all done');
  });

  return false;
});
```

demo: http://jsbin.com/ukovuz/2/

Comment: the other example works just great, had a chain of events i wanted to happend after those got faded in